# Can a single spring application push/produce a message on two kafka clusters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have followed a confluent platform to create 2 kafka clusters, mainly they are 2 brokers with different port number and independent of each other.

***I have created topic A and topic B on those 2 clusters. I want to develop a single spring boot application which will push a message to both topic on those clusters simultaneously.***

Any example help/link would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simply create two producer factories with different bootstrap server properties

If you want to extract the properties outside of the code, then define your own key in application.properties/yml, that's different from `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers`, then annotate a field in your configuration class with `@Value` as you'd do with any other property

Comment: Thanks for your response, but does this look right to you? 
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092, localhost:9082
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

Also I am not using these properties out of spring app:

Comment: No, not comma-delimited in the same property. Create different properties for the second producer outside of the default property

Comment: I see so that would be different yml or just another level of properties in same yml file. An example would be great.

Comment: Same file. `other.bootstrap: <values>`. In your Config class, use [`@Value("${other.bootstrap}")` annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation), as my answer says